# rails link_to :remote

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

I have the following:

```
<%= link_to my_path, method: :delete, confirm: 'Delete?', class: 'link-delete', 'data-message' => 'Are you sure?', 'data-severity' => 'danger', :remote => true do %>
  <i class="icon-trash"></i>
<% end %>
```

which brings up a Bootstrap Modal for confirmation, and I wanted to hook onto the ajax call that so that I can display a spinner or some kind of text.

I know that I can use unobtrusive javascript to listen to the click event like so, if I DON'T use ':remote => true' in my link_to

```
jQuery ->
  $('.link-delete').live 'click', (event) ->
    $('.link-delete').html("Loading...")  #THE MSG OR ANIMATION I WANT TO DISPLAY
    $.get(this.href, null, null, 'script')
   false
```

but not sure how to combine the two when using ':remote => true'

Any suggestions?

thanks for the help

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can bind to ajax calls like this:

```
<%= link_to my_path, method: :delete, confirm: 'Delete?', class: 'link-delete', 'data-message' => 'Are you sure?', 'data-severity' => 'danger', :remote => true do %>
  <i class="icon-trash"></i>
<% end %>

$('.link-delete').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
  $('#mySpinner').show();
});

$('.link-delete').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
  $('#mySpinner').hide();
});
```

Comment: i am trying to do the same thing ..but somehow `ajax:complete` doesnt get fired. Only `beforeSend` is working. Iam using GET in my case.

Comment: @RahulDess Is your server generating a response? The only reason I can imagine for the complete callback not to trigger, is that the requests never completes.

Comment: requests complete successfully ..but noticable point is that i render partial through javascrpipt in my controller . Does thtat change anything ?

Comment: @RahulDess If the controller returns JavaScript that replaces the link (or something containing it), then it would make sense if `ajax:complete` is not triggered since the original link is no longer there in the DOM for the event to propagate from. (This may not be a problem in the spinner case, since the spinner might have been blown away as well.)

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to combine the two. Just use the format.js to call the javascript.

In your controller:

**Controller**

```
 def my_method
     #code here
     respond_to do |format|
      format.js  {}
     end
    end
```

**my_method.html.erb**

```
<div id = "link-delete"></div>
```

**my_method.js.erb**

```
$("#link-delete").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "text_message"))%>");
```

**_text_message.html.erb**

```
<p>Loading...</p>
```

Comment: `$("#link-delete").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "text_message"))%>");`
can be shortened to
`$("#link-delete").html("<%=j render "text_message")%>");`

Comment: wow, I never knew about that. Its nice. But how it will know that you are rendering a partial or just a simple text ? You haven't defined partial in your render.

Comment: Sure, that I knew, but that is after the ajax request is performed. I would like to show a 'Loading... ' message before the ajax call is called.

Comment: but you are using `:remote => true` in your link and it will call ajax on click.

Comment: Basically the 'Loading...' message should be displayed before the action in my controller is called. The problem is that with the Bootstrap modal I seem to lose control of the invocation process.

Comment: @SaurabhJain exactly! And I can't figure out how to hook onto the 'click' event and add custom jQuery/javascript to the actual invocation (like I would if I used my little unobtrusive javascript). At least not when I use the :remote => true

Comment: @SaurabhJain If you provide the render function with just a string argument, rails will look for a partial with that name in it's current context. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Sure and thanks :) but I guess I can't explain myself correctly :( Thanks for the help.