# Render a Rails view in a Bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have hit a brick wall. I've been hacking at this problem for so long now, I'm not even sure how I got to where I am. All I can say is, I've tried all of the below without success:

- [How to add bootstrap modal with link_to so the link content open in modal ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152486/how-to-add-bootstrap-modal-with-link-to-so-the-link-content-open-in-modal#15152960)
- [How to show twitter bootstrap modal via JS request in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529420/how-to-show-twitter-bootstrap-modal-via-js-request-in-rails)
- [rails link_to :remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292270/rails-link-to-remote)
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote

**How do I render "new", "edit" and "delete" views within Bootstrap modals on the "index" view rather than linking to separate pages for each?**

Here is my code as it stands now. For now, lets ignore "edit" and "delete" and just focus on "new". When I click the "New" button, a modal with the string "<%= j render "items/new" %>" appears (instead of the form that that ruby statement should render). What am I doing wrong?:

items_controller.rb:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "'#{@item.name}' saved!"
      redirect_to items_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong :("
      render "index"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  def update
    @item = Item.find(item_params[:id])
    if @item.update_attributes(item_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated #{@item.name}."
      redirect_to items_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Oops"
      # render "edit"
    end
  end

  private
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :bid, :uuid)
    end

end
```

items/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <%= link_to "New", new_item_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-success pull-right new", data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#newModal" } %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <table class="table table-hover items">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>UUID</th>
          <th colspan="2">Links</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= item.id %></td>
            <td><%= item.name %>

              <!-- edit/remove icons -->
              <span class="edit-remove">
                <%= link_to edit_item_path(item.id), remote: true, data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#editModal" } do %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-muted"></span>
                <% end %>
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-muted"></span>
                </a>
              </span>

            </td>
            <td><%= item.uuid %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "XXX", "http://xxx" %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "XXXX", "http://xxx", target: "_blank" %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- newModal skeleton -->
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- editModal skeleton -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- deleteModal skeleton -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

items/new.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">New Item</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= form_for :item, url: { action: "create" } do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, { class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :bid, "BID" %>
      <%= f.text_field :bid, { class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :uuid, "UUID" %>
      <%= f.text_field :uuid, { class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <%= submit_tag "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

javascripts/items.js

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $("#newModal .modal-content").html('<%= j render "items/new" %>');
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of new for instance, you want to render a javascript file. For this, you'll need to create items/new.js.erb.

Also, remove ", data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#newModal" }" from your link, we will do that in the javascript.

```
  # new.js.erb
  $("#newModal .modal-content").html('<%= j render "items/form" %>');
  $("#newModal").modal(); // Or whatever the Bootstrap function is to render the modal


  # items/_form.html.slim
  # Here you'll put your form
```

You cannot use "render" on views directly, you should render partials and not views (this is why I asked you to put your form into a partial).

Comment: I am getting undefined method 'render' when I follow your steps. Can you think of why that would happen?

Comment: Ok, this is the correct answer. Thank you. The reason it didn't work for me at first is because I was placing the new.js.erb file in the javascripts folder instead of the views/items folder. Maybe you could clarify that above for others that may read this. Thank you so much!!! You made my day

Answer (score 0):

I threw this together and it puts a big '3' in my document 3 seconds after loading it:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#holder").html("<%= j render(:file => 'things/test.html.erb') %>");
}, 3000);
</script>
<div id="holder></div>
```

**app/views/things/test.html.erb**:

```
<h1><%= 1 + 2 %></h1>
```

That should get you going.